# Why is data removed from my CV?

Tags: support, status-completed, developer-story

In my [CV](https://stackoverflow.com/cv/xameeramir), a few of the projects from the the experience section of employer **Next** are removed (I see it as a truncation without intimation).

- It was not intimated to me.
- How do I get it back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid communicating this was an oversight when we bulk imported CVs; there was a tiny percentage of CVs (about 20 out of 450,000) that had a large quantity of text in a field that we have limited to 4000 characters for performance reasons. An analysis of those CVs indicated that most of them had *whole CVs* pasted into that field.

Longer term you should break large items into a sequence of separate project or position/job items on the developer Story. Not only does that satisfy the character limit but, as somebody that reviews a lot of resumés, I'd suggest that it's much easier to grok than the wall of text you currently have.

We still have all your CV data; I'm unable to get at my laptop today (we're all returning from our annual meetup) but I can contact you over email with the full text that you had for that experience section. Stay tuned.

Comment: But what is the loss to `StackOverflow` if they allowed the CV link also. I'm your end user and why're you guys not understanding that? +1 because you can help me get the data atleast

Comment: CVs are done, deprecated, no longer accessible. I don't know any other way to put it. We provide the traditional view which is also the default for employers. You can link to the traditional view of your story and will be able to forever, it's just the editing and story views that are different.

Comment: Help me get the data on my email, please

Comment: I've sent the missing data to your email.